# h2 VS spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, h2

We have a Spring Boot (v 1.5.2) project setup with a h2 in-memory db for local development. Since it is a pretty new project, we do not have legacy code (yet..) to [handle legacy id-generators](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#generator-mappings). So we set `spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings: true`.

By providing `src/main/resources/data.sql` we add some initial data. The file contains nothing but `insert` commands, let's say for entity `A`.

Our Entity has the following id generator configured:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
```

This, however, results in the following error, when trying to store another entry (i.e. `aRepo.save(newA)`).

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.A(ID)"; SQL statement:
insert into a (something, id) values (?, ?)
```

Setting `spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings: false` or not inserting initial data do both fix the issue. However, we would rather want to understand why the above configuration would not work and whether we could make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate simply maintains session for each entry.Please check weather you close the previous session in your service. In not means close and flush your session.

Your database connection is not closed properly.

```
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
public <return Type> serviceFunction() { 
  session.save(newA);
  session.flush();
  session.close();
}
```

You need to close each session else model class couldn't change your Id.It it remains the same.
Hope that it will help you.